How to get the current zoom level in the TWebLeafletMaps component?
I'm allowing users to zoom in and out on the TWebLeafletMaps component in my TMS WEB Core application through the zoom buttons top left:

But is there a way for me to know what zoom level they are on?
I want to save the user's zoom level, so that I can automatically take them to their previous zoom level when opening the map. But to do this, I need to know what zoom level they're on.
How can I capture or get the zoom level, meaning how far they are zoomed in or out on the map?
